# BeautifulSoup не возвращает html

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Новичок в парсинге, нужна подсказка специалистов. Хочу обнаружить теги на сайте, чтобы в дальнейшем парсить его, но soup не возращает теги.

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

time.sleep(0.3)
req = requests.get('https://old.bankrot.fedresurs.ru/ArbitrManagersList.aspx')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
soup
```

Результат

```
<html><body>setting cookie...<script src="/aes.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("36540638379070ff9487296b05ef3fd5"),b=toNumbers("8d2c272c52cb3c97e659a008596763ec"),c=toNumbers("f737afaaea0529b007f07c24b86d6093"),now = new Date(), time = now.getTime();time += 3600 * 1000;now.setTime(time);document.cookie="bankrotcookie="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires="+now.toUTCString()+"; path=/";location.href="https://old.bankrot.fedresurs.ru/ArbitrManagersList.aspx?attempt=1";</script></body></html>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в сторону какого метода или библиотеки копать?

Answer (score 1):

В python есть много библиотек (даже встроенные вроде), которые вырезают из текста теги html, можете применять к разметке, и сравнивать обработанную и изначальную, по разнице понимать где теги.

**Либо же написать свой метод, который будет вырезать их по спец.символам**

Comment: вырезать то я вырежу, но как сначала мне получить html код? приведенный выше скрипт возвращает только код JS

Comment: html тоже есть в Вашем ответе, просто Вы парсите сайт на этапе загрузки, попробуйте запрашивать страницу и немного ждать

Comment: @AdiKou не правильно понял Ваш вопрос

Comment: Я пробовал парсить не на этапе загрузки страницы, а подождав пока загрузится полностью. Результат тот же, возвращает только js

Comment: Попробуйте парсить эту ссылку https://old.bankrot.fedresurs.ru/ArbitrManagersList.aspx?attempt=1

Comment: Кстати, скорее всего этот сайт не запарсите, он как раз против парсеров сделан, вообще изи обходится, но учитывайте